# Is it possible to create a user with all admin rights *except* the ability to interrupt a particular process and access a particular folder?

Tags: permission, sudo, root

On Windows, it's not really doable. It is possible on linux with mandatory access control (for example). So you can have a web filter running, but the sudoer wouldn't be able to interfere with it (at least not without lots of effort, potentially rendering the system inoperable). At the same time a sudoer can modify virtually everything else.

What options would I have on OS X to do this?

Comment: This post may be helpful:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313373/block-specific-apps-on-macos/313393#313393

Comment: I’ve edited out the part where you don’t even have a Mac - this will make it harder for you to judge which answer works and also makes this more of a theoretical question than something practical, but it’s a great question and perhaps some day you’ll get macOS to play with and can answer even better than we will. It’s pretty broad, but an overview answer might help a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t see any way you could accomplish this without rewriting the OS and security models.

- The accessing a specific folder will be trivially handled when you encrypt the contents of a folder or file and don’t share the key to unlock the data on APFS. Since you can’t keep the root user from reading a file or folder, and admin user can become root (that’s the definition of Admin user on macOS) therefore anything one admin user can set, another can undo.
- The prevention of the ability of any admin user to send [SIGKILL (or any other interesting IPC commands)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)) to any running process will be problematic technically without modifying the OS itself.

The best you can do is try to rely on Gatekeeper and preventing `sudo` from your admin user per this very excellent question:

- [Block Specific Apps on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313373/block-specific-apps-on-macos)

I can’t see a case where you wouldn’t just make the user not an admin and carve out a way they can do whatever admin things you want them to do by granting additional access and just not granting admin status to the users you don’t trust.