# How can I use Gatekeeper to block applications on my Mac?

Tags: terminal, macos, applications

Is there a way for me to create a blacklist of Applications that cannot be installed, or run after they have been installed, on OS X Sierra? I have tried to follow the directions outlined here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313393/  but all applications still run even after I add them using the spctl command. Essentially, I would like to be able to create a list of applications based on something static like the bundle identifier (so that applications that are redownloaded are still blocked), and keep these applications from working on my Mac. These would include system applications (such as Mail) as well as Applications with valid developer identities.

Thank You.