# Irreversible way to block Internet access on Mac for certain periods of time

Tags: macos, mac, internet

I am looking for a way to restrict Internet access for specified periods of time that I decide on so that I, the admin, cannot access the internet during the restricted time period, and that I also cannot override this in any way even though I am the admin, except by formatting my hard disk and reinstalling my OS.

I am not looking for reversible methods like a browser add-on or parental controls (I'm the admin) or router changes (I do not own the router). I want something at the level of the OS, something that requires administrator privileges (of course something like this cannot be done other than by an admin), and something irreversible.

I would be grateful and very happy to adopt any way of reaching my goal.

Comment: Permanent than ?

Comment: No not permanent, I would like it to be for certain specified periods of time

Comment: so you want to lock you self out, trow the key away, then try to find it

Comment: No. I want to lock myself out, melt the key so that it is not functional, and then have another key given to me at a time that I decide on before locking myself out.

Comment: Also, may I please understand why my question was downvoted so much? I am new to this website, and I don't know what was wrong with my question.

Comment: Idk why this got so many downvotes either, except maybe that https://selfcontrolapp.com is first hit on google.

Comment: But I did not mention the word website, I always used the word Internet, to mean anything that is online. How is that app relevant?

Comment: This probably got the number of downvotes it did because paras 1 and 2 contradict each other re:  what an admin can/can't do.

Comment: Not even the moderators can reverse the down votes, but if you need help in combining your accounts please the [contact page](https://apple.stackexchange.com/contact) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's clear up a misconception....

> I am looking for a way to restrict ... that I decide on so that I, the
> admin, cannot access ... and that I also cannot override this in any
> way even though I am the admin...that requires administrator
> privileges (of course something like this cannot be done other than by
> an admin), and something irreversible.

#### In other words, can you (as an admin) modify the OS to prevent an activity that another admin cannot circumvent?

***No.  Anything one admin can do, another can undo.***

That's not to say that you can't make it *very difficult* to do the "undoing."  So, here's a short recipe using the *built-in* firewall, `pf` to achieve a relatively good bit of what you're trying to accomplish.

#### Use `pf` to "disable" your Internet

- create your own `pf.conf` firewall ruleset that blocks all Internet traffic
- [Create a `launchd` plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) that enables/disables `pf` at certain times of the day.
- Block *your* `sudo` access to `pfctl` by [modifying your `sudoers` file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313393/119271).

The meat and potatoes to blocking your Internet access is `pf` so, we'll look at that here.

#### Block Internet Access

You can block all of your Internet access with a really simple rule set.  So, assuming the pf rule are set in the file `~/pf/pf_block_all.conf`, just set the following two lines:

```
block in all
block out all
```

You can then "break" your Internet with the simple command by enabling `pf` and specifying the custom rule set.

```
$ sudo pfctl -e -f ~/pf/pf_block_all.conf
```

When you're ready to have Internet again, just disable `pf`

```
$ sudo pfctl -d
```

(Go ahead, try this out to see how it blocks the Internet).

#### Running the `launchd` plist

You would want to run this as a LaunchDaemon because then, it will execute as `root` and you wouldn't need the `sudo` function to execute.  You would need two plists run at certain intervals; one to enable and another to disable `pf`.  [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249452/119271) goes into detail on how to achieve this.

#### Blocking access to `pfctl`

To remove the ability of you just typing in `sudo pfctl ....` you will need to remove (well, at least make it difficult) permission to execute.  In the `/etc/sudoers` file you can exclude a program with the following entry:

```
Tim ALL = ALL, !/sbin/pfctl
```

That will prevent you from executing `pfctl`, but there are workarounds to this.  See the link above.

Answer (score 2):

No, there’s no irreversible way. At the extreme, an admin could always just reinstall macOS from scratch, or change the system clock so that the blackout period expires early. You’d need a firmware option to disable the network hardware for a specific period of time, and an unchangeable firmware clock, and such things do not exist.