# How do I stop a user unloading a plist

Tags: terminal, launchd

I want to stop a user in MacOS from unloading a plist using launchctl?

Launchctl does not seem to always require a su / sudo. I have a non-admin user that is managing to switch off app restrictions and adjust various processes that are running.

I don't want to block Terminal, which is my current solution.

Comment: Is it a launch daemon or a launch agent? Daemons shouldn't be disablable without admin access.

Comment: You needn't block _Terminal_, but you can restrict the privileges of just his specific user account, either in what he can do through a shell, or by setting the permissions of the `~/Library` and other similar folders so that only administrators and `wheel` or `root` can edit/view/etc.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313393/119271).  In short, use Gatekeeper and disallow access

Comment: launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/...

it's not asking for a su password... so they can unload app restrictions.  I am not sure how a non-admin account is managing this.  At the moment I have just renamed and moved Terminal to a local App folder for an Admin account (with SIP disabled) as a not so sexy solution...

Comment: i can't lock ~/Library/ to Admin accounts because a local user can just change the permissions and it stops most apps working properly.  Firefox won't even launch.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to unload a launch daemon except as root (i.e. with `sudo` or `su`). Something *really* weird is going on here, and I think you'd be better off trying to figure out what it is than to try to patch symptoms like this.