# macOS: Blacklisting applications and processes

Tags: macos, security

I need something like a firewall, but instead of restricting network traffic, I want to be able to restrict scripts, applications, and processes in general from being allowed to run/execute in the first place.

Rather than having to constantly keep checking for rogue processes, troubleshooting, and terminating them individually. I just want them to:

a) Die. Quickly, quietly, without manual user intervention.

Or (preferably):

b) Be prevented from ever spawning in the first place.

PS: I don't think the old `chmod` utility is really appropriate at this level. I think I recall reading about an Apple style `.plist`/`.xml` solution for this kind of thing. I don't know enough about it to say if it's the right approach though.

Comment: Right now you are asking several questions at once: "Are all these Adobe processes necessary or does Illustrator work without them", "How can I prevent specific processes from getting created" and (implicitly) "do low-prio background processes impact available memory/performance". If the question is about blacklisting, please edit it down to exactly that. You can always ask additional questions separately.

Comment: @nohillside I've asked exactly one question here today. I was very clear about that.

Comment: At least related: [Block Specific Apps on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313373/block-specific-apps-on-macos)

Comment: I‘ve removed the part about Adobe to help the readers focus on the blacklisting part. Having said that: does the link posted in the comments help to solve the problem?

Comment: @nohillside In my opinion the Abobe part of the question just illustrated the OP's issue as an example. Both sides though (from the perspective of a person answering the question): the legitimate interest of a user to block apps/daemons/scripts to lower the app's footprint/disable bloated services/keep privacy etc. and the difficulty for a user/power user/admin to determine which helper apps/scripts/services are really necessary.

Comment: Adobe is going to be a super special case, since it’s a very complicated, web of interconnected apps and daemons and services. Let’s get some answers on the easier general case. I’m hoping this is Catalina specific as it’s the best case for using new systems and controls.