# Big Sur: remove per-user permissions for builtin apps

Tags: macos, permission, big-sur

I am trying to create a limited user account without access to several builtin apps, such as Terminal.

Changing these apps permissions either through `Finder` or `chmod` failed - I assume due to them being in the write-protected `/System` volume. I've also tried to copy them over to `/Applications` and change permissions on the copy instead, but that only leads to them appearing twice in `Finder`.

Is there an officially sanctioned way for access control left that doesn't involve me disabling SIP and remounting /System as read-write? `Screentime` is not an option for me, because I've found it to be highly unreliable on iOS.

Comment: Did you look into Parental Control?

Comment: @nohillside aren't parental controls gone and folded into Screentime?

Comment: Ah right, has been I while since I needed this.

Comment: Have you worked through the answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313373/block-specific-apps-on-macos which uses spctl.

Comment: @Gilby thanks for the link! That's clever, and I had not seen it before. Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, because the restrictions aren't per-user, but global.